# Show images coming from mongodb into java swing

Tags: java, image, swing, mongodb, photo

i'm a newbie in Java and Mongodb. Till now all works fine but now i complete stuck. I can write and retrieve images to and from Mongodb. But how i can show them on screen. I know i can get them from the folder but i like to show the image direct from database into, in this case because i learning, into swing.

i guess i need to convert them? OR how does it works?

```
Database dbb = new Database(mc, dba);
DB dbc1 = dbb.getDatabase("aatestdb");
String newFileName = "test foto";
GridFS gfsPhotoa = new GridFS(dbc1, "photofile");
GridFSDBFile imageForOutput = gfsPhotoa.findOne(newFileName);
System.out.println ("show i receive data");

// proof i got image from dbimageForOutput.writeTo("/Users/xyz/Pictures/foto_offshore_site/java_app.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically in Swing you can use a JLabel and ImageIcon to show an image. If you can get your GridFSDBFile into an InputStream, you could try [ImageIO.read(InputStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.InputStream)) This may or may not work. If it doesn't work, you are going to have to get an ImageReader for the specific kind of image you are dealling with

Comment: What i got is a file of the type "GridFSDBFile" what i can not display via Jlabel. I can not (or at least i do not know how) convert it into a image / icon or what ever i can use.  In this sample i like to convert imageForOutput into a binary or Image type (java) and return it to the caller "a swing / awt" program and indeed show it with jlabel. But i'm unsuccessful till now.